# How to remember css class on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually I want to add class for anchor tag on click of a tag but it is hiding on load of a page. In my case I want to refresh my page after loading also it should add class for whichever is clicked. How to resolve this?

Code (using JQuery):

```js
$(".category_filter").click(function() {
  // alert("coming");return false;
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  //return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<div class="flDropDiv category_fl">
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/full-bed-sheets"> Full bed sheets   </a> </div>
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/fitted-bed-sheet"> Fitted bed Sheet  </a> </div>
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/flat-bed-sheet"> Flat bed sheet  </a> </div>
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/twin-bed-sheet"> Twin bed sheet  </a> </div>
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/twinxl-bed-sheets"> Twinxl bed sheets   </a> </div>
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/queen-bed-sheet"> Queen bed sheet  </a> </div>
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/king-bed-sheets"> King bed sheets  </a> </div>
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/cal-king-bed-sheets"> Cal king bed sheets  </a> </div>
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/duvet-covers"> Duvet covers  </a> </div>
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/bed-skirts"> Bed skirts  </a> </div>
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/standard-pillow-cases"> Standard Pillow cases  </a> </div>
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/king-pillow-cases"> King Pillow cases  </a> </div>
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/pillow-shells"> Pillow shells  </a> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On refresh your changes will be gone.
You can do 2 things - 
1. Save clicked item into Localstorage or cookie, and on load if there is any tag saved then add selected class to that one.
2. Or you can save selected tag to backend and on load get through ajax and add class if anyone is selected.

Comment: You can either use localstorage or cookies for persisting the data, if you dont it wont work if the page reloads.

Comment: How to store in local storage?

Comment: see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 1):

#### Compare `href` to `window.location.href`

You can compare the current `window.location.href` to the `href` of the link.
This will **not** need any cookies, localStorage, webSQL or anything.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.flItems a.category_filter').each(function() {
    // Comparing the href attribute to see if this is the selected page
    if ($(this).prop('href') === window.location.href) {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
  });
});
```

This is likely your intention, just highlight the current page.
A user who never clicked one of the links would otherwise not see the selected content in your navigation.

The above solution will work no matter how they use your website (provided JavaScript is enabled, of course).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. This code below is more of a guidance for you.

It has your sample HTML with some added id-s

```js
//On page load - add selected class to clicked elements
$(document).ready(function() {
  let allCookies = getCookies();
  for (let cookie in allCookies) {
    if (allCookies[cookie] === "clicked") {
      $("#" + cookie.trim()).addClass("selected");
    }
  }
});


//On item click - add selected class and remember it in cookie for later usage
$(".category_filter").click(function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  setCookie(this.id, "clicked", 1);
});

//Gets all the cookies 
function getCookies() {
  var pairs = document.cookie.split(";");
  var cookies = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
    cookies[pair[0]] = unescape(pair[1]);
  }
  return cookies;
}

//add new cookie
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<div class="flDropDiv category_fl">
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" id="category_filter_1" href="#1"> Full bed sheets   </a> </div>
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" id="category_filter_2" href="#2"> Fitted bed Sheet  </a> </div>
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" id="category_filter_3" href="#3"> Fitted bed Sheet  </a> </div>
  <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" id="category_filter_4" href="#4"> Fitted bed Sheet  </a> </div>
</div>
```

---

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/combine/kynf69vf/1/) is a fiddle that you can test everything.

You can use my code above and tweak it to work even without id-s but is slightly more complicated. I added IDs only for the sake of clear understanding of how things work.